# Can't catch _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError in Flask app

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a Flask app with a route that looks like this:

```
from _mysql_exceptions import OperationalError

@mod.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def do_something_route():
    try:
        do_something(request.form)
    except OperationalError:
        message = {"error": "something went wrong"}
        return jsonify(message, mimetype='application/json'), 400
```

The `do_something()` function:

```
def do_something(self, form_data):
    model = MyModel()
    for key in form_data:
        if hasattr(model, key):
            setattr(model, key, form_data.get(key))
    db.session.add(model)
    db.session.commit()
    return model
```

When I send garbage data to `do_something_route` that violates my DB constraints, an `OperationalError` exception is raised and a response with a status code of 500 and the stack trace is returned, not my jsonified message with a status of 400.

When I try this is a plain old python shell, it seems to work as expected:

```
>>> from _mysql_exceptions import OperationalError
>>> raise OperationalError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError

>>> try:
...     raise OperationalError
... except OperationalError:
...     print 'test'
...
test
```

Why is `except OperationalError:` not catching `OperationalError` exceptions? Is Flask doing some black magic that is returning a response early?

Comment: [SQLAlchemy raises its own exceptions. Catch those.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/exceptions.html) Edit: New working link: [SQLAlchemy raises its own exceptions. Catch those. New Link][1]
[1]: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html

Answer (score 2):

```
from  sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
try:
     # do something
except OperationalError:
     # do something
```

Comment: Also try this solution if you are getting a `pymysql.err.OperationalError` but not able to catch it.